# Automatic vertical scroll on page load

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having a react project.

When users reach a page, they don't realize there are more options only if they scroll down.

So I want to automatically scroll vertically in a smooth way,  on page load to show users all the options they have.

What is the way to achieve this in react?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 ways.

First is to transition the entire page with animation on load.

CSS

```
body{
animation: scrollUp 1s;
}

@keyframes scrollUp {
from {transform: translate(1000px)}
to{transform: translate()}
}
```

Second would be to set window.scroll value manually on page load to lets say 1000 or whereever you want and then use window.scroll to smoothly scroll to top.

Before first render (maybe use requestAnimationFrame)

```
window.scrollTo(1000, 0)
```

Then on next frame

```
window.scroll({
  top: 0, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/